# sass watch files in folder and minify, but control output filename

Tags: sass

I know that I can watch a single file in a folder and have it compressed like so:

```
sass --watch HealthyArticles.scss:HealthyArticles.min.css --style compressed
```

What I'd like to be able to do is:

```
sass --watch *.scss:*.min.css --style compressed
```

The problem with this is that I get the error:

```
Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument - *.scss
```

The main point is controlling the output filename. Is this possible with sass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're probably looking for Compass. All this stuff is just baked into Rails, so I'm not sure exactly how everything links together, but I believe if you're using SCSS without a framework around it, then Compass is what you're after.

Download from http://compass-style.org/ and run something like this:

```
gem install compass 
$ compass create asd --bare --sass-dir "input_directory" --css-dir "output_directory"
```

You can set this in a config file:

```
output_style = :compressed
```

Alternatively, you could just run a script that does something like (this is Ruby):

```
files = Dir["/path/to/scss/folder/*.scss"].map do |file|
  "#{file}:#{file.gsub(".scss", ".min.css")}"
end
`sass --watch #{files} --style compressed`
```

Comment: In the end I went for this approach: `sass --watch Styles/:Styles/min/ --style compressed`